# Javascript data check will always return true

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my java script, where I am checking if data comes do some thing else do something

```
function translateData() {
    var word = $('#word').val();
    var lang = $('#lang').val();
    $("#result").html("loading...");
    $.post("translateAdmin.action", {
        word : word,lang:lang
    }, function(data) {
        if (data.length > 0) {
            $().toastmessage('showSuccessToast', "Translation Done");

            //alert("Translation Done");

        }
        else {

            $().toastmessage('showErrorToast', "Translation Not Done");
           // alert("Unable to translate");
        }
```

But, it will never go to else, even if it does not return any data in text area, it shows exception in my action class but it give an success message.

Comment: log 'data' please and show us the result

Comment: If it's json, you have {} empty object.

Comment: You should change your if-condition to sth. different. Because for example, the server receives a 500-ErrorMessage, your JavaScript will still popup "Translation done" even if its not. You should always return JSON in your "translateAdmin.action" like this: {status: 'success', 'translatedWord': 'Cheesy'}. You could then use the following condition: if (typeof data.status !== 'undefined' && data.status === 'success') { .. } else { .. }.

But we can't help you since we don't know what kind of data your translateAdmin.action returns.

Comment: my translateAdmin.action will return a list

Comment: How do I send list in josn along with string?